# Firebase: functions: Upload Error: Server Error. Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

- This is a fresh firebase functions project made by firebase-CLI but not work deploy function.
- I uninstall firebase-tools and then install it but not working.
- Logout to firebase and then log in again but not working.
  [This is CLI problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJTa9.png)

Comment: If you're having problems deploying with the CLI and the error message isn't helpful, contact Firebase support directly for assistance.  https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Comment: I did contact with firebase support

Comment: any update @RayhanulIslam? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: 1. Update to the latest version of Firebase CLI by running this command: npm install -g firebase-tools@latest
2. Also, update to the newest version of the Firebase Admin SDK and the Functions SDK by running these commands in your functions folder "npm install firebase-functions@latest --save" and "npm install firebase-admin@latest --save-exact"
3. Also, try deleting a function and deploying only one using this command: firebase deploy --only functions:functionName
4. Try different networks more and more times

After following this stapes sometimes deploy work, not fully solved